# matlab, how could i read from multiple folders

Tags: c, matlab, file, directory

I wanna read multiple pics from multiple folders, assume that, I have an animal folder in drive D, and I have cat,dog,koala sub-folders in it, each sub-folder has 5 pics of animals. how could i read this pics and process them? Please explain me by details.
I wrote this code for one folder:

```
cd dog
tasavir = dir('*.jpg');
n = length(tasavir); 
figure;
for i=1:n
   esm = tasavir(i).name;
   t = imread(esm);
   ss{i} = t;
   subplot(5,2,i),imshow(ss{i})
end
```

Comment: Have a look at some functions for walking through directory tree. For example this [one](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32036-dirwalk-walk-the-directory-tree).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Given your structure you can do something like this:

```
workDir = cd;
cd('D:\'); % start in parent directory
dirs = dir();

for dIdx = 1:length(dirs)
    curDir = dirs(dIdx).name;
    if isdir(curDir) % is directory?
        cd(curDir);
        % RUN YOUR CODE FOR A SINGLE DIRECTORY
        cd('..');
    end
end
cd(workDir);
```